# On creating office365 account, I cannot view the options for mail,calendar, people

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an office365 account in https://www.office.com/ and on logging in I am not able to see the option for mail, calendar, people.
please refer the image link :[homepage on logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG0hn.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have subscribed to a plan that does not include Exchange Online. There are a number of Office 365 plans and not all of them include Exchange (which provides the backend for Mail, Calendar, etc).

I would suggest looking at the [Plan Comparison](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans) to make sure your subscription includes the features you are looking for. In this case you are looking for a plan that includes Exchange Online (look for this [image: Exchange Online Icon] icon)